# Found some VBA code in a project and I'm wondering what this line does

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a question about a line of code in a vba project I am working on.  What does this statement actually mean?  I know there is no context here and I could post more code but I'm not sure if someone could just look at this and let me know what this is doing.

```
txtTerminationDate.Locked = (isLocked Or cboTypeSelect.Column(1) = "Regular")
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.locked is a boolean that sets whether you can edit the text box.  So it is trying to set it to either true or false based on the logic that follows.

In English, set locked to true if the boolean isLocked is true, or if the value of cboTypeSelect.Column(1) equals "Regular".

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something like that but wanted to be 100% sure before I made some changes to the code.

Answer (score 1):

if you are asking about TextBox.Locked research can be found here (as answered above) [TextBox.Locked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844765.aspx)

if you are asking about the equal signs, it is useful to know that the first one is an assignment operator and the second is a comparison operator (like an inline if comparison).  The equal sign is said to be 'overloaded' in vb.

Comment: Thanks but what I was asking, and I probably should have been more clear, is the "or" statement.  What was actually being assigned to the boolean locked in either of those scenarios.

Comment: True or false. If one of those conditions is true, it will be true. If neither of those conditions are true, it will be false.